# Keyboard grid still visible after dismissing the keyboard, iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, storyboard

I found a strange layer in my view using spark inspector. The previous view had a search bar with an open keyboard. When the user navigates forward to a detail view, the keyboard is still visible, wrapped by **UITextEffectsWindow**. And when I go back to the first view, the keyboard is still visible too. It is not visible on the actual view in simulator, but spark inspector shows it, see image:

[image]

Is this default behaviour or a bug in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

to dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.5; 
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){  
    [self.someTextfield resignFirstResponder];  
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; //Any one of these
});
```

Hope, it works